# How to map a Neo4j node using embeddable objects?

Tags: java, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm asking if this is doable in **Spring-Data-Neo4j (SDN)** or **Neo4j OGM** because I understand that SDN actually uses Neo4j-OGM underneath.

Assume I have 2 Java objects that I need to map to a **single** Graph node:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    private ComplexInfo info;
}
@NodeEntity
public class ComplexInfo {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    private Long age;
    private String name;
}
```

This way, I'll have a relation between **2 nodes**. **User** and **ComplexInfo**.

But is there a way to map this as a **single** node, where the primitive variables (including String and wrapper Objects such as Long, Integer..etc) of the **ComplexInfo** java object would be persisted within the User node and there would be no existence of the **ComplexInfo** node ?

Effectively it would be as if I have mapped my **User** object this way:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    private Long age;
    private String name;
}
```

I don't want to have 2 nodes for this because the **ComplexInfo** class is no more than a collection of reusable properties and there is no benefit of having a relationship between it and the node having this properties.

Comment: This is posible only in the latest OGM - 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT release. You can chek [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215170/spring-data-neo4j-4-how-to-implement-composite-attribute-at-class) for more info. I  hope to see 2.1.0 release soon, I'm waiting for this improvement as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you are after ***embedding*** the `ComplexInfo` class into the `User` class. To be clear this means that `ComplexInfo` will not appear in the database as a node and cannot be directly looked up through the OGM; it must always be accessed through composition of an annotated domain object.

As `@troig` mentions the only way to do this is to upgrade to the latest snapshot version of the OGM (2.1 GA will be out around 12th December). You can then follow Jasper's example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40215787/2271422).  It should be pretty easy to work with your domain. Just remember to remove the `@NodeEntity` annotation and the `@GraphId Long id` field in `ComplexInfo`.

Comment: Thanks for giving an approximate release date :)

Comment: Hi @digx1! Any news about the expected 2.1 GA release? Thanks

Comment: @troig. It was released on the 12th as planned: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-ogm-core/2.1.0

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @digx1! I wasn't looking in the right place... https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/releases